# ASP.NET Health Monitoring in IIS 7.5 Integrated Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, iis-7.5, health-monitoring

I can't seem to get health monitoring to log events when I'm running in integrated mode. If I switch the application pool to run in classic mode, it works fine.

Am I missing some kind of configuration or IIS setup to get this working?

This is my health monitoring config section:

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true">
  <bufferModes>
    <add name="CriticalBufferMode"
         maxBufferSize="100"
         maxFlushSize="20"
         urgentFlushThreshold="1"
         regularFlushInterval="Infinite"
         urgentFlushInterval="00:01:00"
         maxBufferThreads="1"/>
  </bufferModes>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="HealthMonitoring"
       maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823"
       buffer="true"
       bufferMode="CriticalBufferMode"
       name="SqlWebEventProvider"
       type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider" />
    <add name="MailEventProvider"
        type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider"
        from="test@test.com"
        to="test@test.com"
        buffer="true"
        bufferMode="CriticalBufferMode"
        maxEventLength="4096"
        bodyHeader="Error information"
        maxMessagesPerNotification="10" />
  </providers>
  <profiles>
    <add name="Critical" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00"/>
  </profiles>
  <eventMappings>
    <clear />
    <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647" />
  </eventMappings>
  <rules>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AllErrorsSql" eventName="All Errors" provider="SqlWebEventProvider" profile="Critical"/>
    <add name="AllErrorsMail" eventName="All Errors" provider="MailEventProvider" profile="Critical"  />
  </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

Comment: Is your application MVC or ASP.NET forms?

Comment: It's a web forms application.

Comment: Is this related to [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495212/asp-net-application-goes-to-500-21-until-iis-reset-clear-tempoary-asp-net/328685) regarding certain WCF / ASP.NET startup scenarios?